# How to synchronize system date/time?

Tags: date, time, windows-7, synchronized

How to synchronize system date/time with the date/time on workstation in Windows 7? I am trying to use ADO.Net from devArt to connect to Oracle DB from Windows CE (Compact Framework). I want to use 30 days trial to test it before I buy it.

I am getting this error:

> Sorry, your trial period has expired.
>
> Support:
>
> The possible reason may be that the system date/time of the device is
>   not synchronized with the date/time on your workstation; hence, the
>   issue can be resolved by setting the same date/time as set on the
>   workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to http://windowstipoftheday.blogspot.cz/2010/03/windows-7-automatically-syncronzing.html

FTA:

- In the Start menu search field type "Date and Time" and press Enter, this should be bring the Date and Time control panel
- In the Date and Time dialog box, click the Internet Time tab.
- Press the Change Settings button. Press the Continue button in the User Account Control dialog box (if it displays).
- In the Internet Time Settings dialog, click the Server drop-down arrow and select another time server. The default is time.windows.com, try using time.nist.gov and see it works for you.
- Press the Update now button to update your computer's clock, and test your computer's
- Press the OK buttons close the dialog boxes.

For users with domain accounts, try using this command line command: `w32tm /config /syncfromflags:MANUAL /manualpeerlist:time.nist.gov w32tm /config /update` (thanks to @user6852928 for this).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I just googled that tab isnt there if you are in domain. I found solution to use cmd commands:

w32tm /config /syncfromflags:MANUAL /manualpeerlist:time.nist.gov
w32tm /config /update

and it seems not helped to allow that library works.

Comment: I am sorry this hasn't helped you fix the library issue (consider contacting the authors). I have included the `cmd` way in my library as well so people with domain accounts can benefit from the answer as well.